# Why do style declarations inside the body selector not override Bootstrap styles?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning Bootstrap, and I can't understand why using body selector does not override default Bootstrap styles. Meanwhile, my own styles apply when using a universal selector (*). Here is the HTML (you see that I'm linking Bootstrap before my style sheet):

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>David Chu's China Bistro</title>

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oxygen:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to set my own font styles, and it's not working. However, it changes with a universal selector (*). What's the problem?

Comment: Why not just use `*` then? Could you provide reasoning? Also ~ what version of BS?

Comment: So I'm following the course "HTML, CSS and JavaScript for web developers" on Coursera. And the teacher does just like me: first linking Bootstrap, then his own style sheet, in which he sets some font properties inside the body selector (without !important) and they actually apply, meaning that Bootstrap styles were overriden.
Maybe that's because I'm using the latest version of Bootstrap, and he used like Bootstrap 3, because the course is a little outdated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening here is that your CSS rules for `body` are being overridden by the bootstrap properties for other more specific elements, like `h1`. Your rules will only apply to plain text within the body element.

CSS behaves by the [rules of specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). When specificity is equivalent, the CSS precedence goes from:

1. HTML elements with a `style` attribute
2. `<style>` tag inside of an HTML document
3. External CSS documents, with last loaded taking precedence

It's worth noting that any CSS property with the `!important` declaration raises the item in the precedence stack, but that can be overridden if a competing CSS property elsewhere in the chain also has an `!important` declaration.